# Анимация и рендеринг в React. Глючит анимация, как бороться?

Tags: reactjs, анимация, transition

У меня есть боковая панель, внутри которой в момент ее выдвижения (средствами css transition) рендерится список. Из-за этого  анимация глючит и затормаживается, панель выезжает обрывками.

Как с этим бороться.

Пробовал сначала рендерить, потом выдвигать, но тогда выдвижение происходит с задержкой, что не очень мне подходит.

Спасибо

```
 //React.js

 class Panel extands React.Component{

   renderList = () => {
      return(
        this.state.data.map((item, index) => (
        <li key = {index}>{item}</li>
       ))
      )
   }


   render(){
      return(
        <div className = {'Panel'}>
           <ul>
              {this.state.PanelActive && this.renderList()}
           </ul>
        </div>
      )
   }
 }


//styles.css

 .Panel{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    right: -100%;
    transition: right 250ms ease-out;
 }

 .PanelActive{
    right: 0 !inportant;
 }
```

Comment: Лучше 1 строчку кода, чем тысяча слов (с)

Comment: я так понял у Вас смешана js и css анимация?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, да

Comment: @DmitryFilippov у меня для Вас плохие новости...

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, что такое?(

Comment: @DmitryFilippov у меня частенько не получалось их совместить, нужно делать либо одно либо второе, либо чтобы они во времени не пересекались